# boxCox Error in model.frame.default : 'data' must be a data.frame, environment, or list

Tags: r, linear-regression, transformation

This data is from an excel CSV file.

I want to see if a transformation is necessary, but my problem is that I keep getting this message:

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = comment$Number.of.Comments ~ comment$Character.Count + : 'data' must be a data.frame, environment, or list
```

The following is my code:

```
comment <- read.csv('AdAnalysis3.csv', header = TRUE, fileEncoding = "UTF-8-BOM")
commentfit <- lm(comment$Number.of.Comments ~ comment$Character.Count + comment$Number.of.Shares + comment$Number.of.Likes + comment$Type.of.Ad + comment$Dealing.with.Life + comment$Christlike.Attributes + comment$Spiritual.Learning, data = comment)
library(car)
boxCox(commentfit)
```

I get the following message immediately after boxCox(commentfit):

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You haven't given us a reproducible example, but my guess is that you have confused `car::boxCox()` by including `comment$` in your formula. In general it's better (for a number of reasons including clarity) to specify a linear model with just the variable names, i.e.:

```r
commentfit <- lm(Number.of.Comments ~ Character.Count + Number.of.Shares +
    Number.of.Likes + Type.of.Ad + Dealing.with.Life + 
    Christlike.Attributes + Spiritual.Learning, 
   data = comment)
```