# How to address "Error in model.frame.default(y, data = i) : 'data' must be a data.frame, environment, or list'" when i is in fact a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, regression

The code used in this question comes from the "BE & FS using olsrr (practice version)" and "BE and FS Stepwise Regressions" Rscripts in my [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/Spencermstarr/EER-Research-Project) for this project.
I will preface this question by saying that I did look up similar questions using this same error in the search bar, but as I suspected, none of the ones near the top were super similar, because in my situation, the "i" in question is in fact a dataframe as you will see.

*The overall goal of this script is to figure out how to write a new script which can reproduce results I am generating using the step function (the 1st direction = 'backward' and the 2nd with direction = 'forward') from R's stats package in my "BE and FS Stepwise Regressions", this time using the ols_step_backward_aic and ols_step_forward_aic functions from R's olsrr package.*

I have already written the following code which does work for my intended purpose of running an individual Backward Elimination Stepwise Regression or an individual Forward Selection Stepwise Regression on each of N different synthetic datasets:

```
set.seed(11)      # for reproducibility
system.time( BE.fits <- parLapply(cl = CL, X = datasets, \(X) {
  full_models <- lm(X$Y ~ ., X)
  back <- stats::step(full_models, scope = formula(full_models), 
                      direction = 'backward', trace = FALSE) }) )

set.seed(11)      # for reproducibility
system.time( FS.fits <- parLapply(cl = CL, X = datasets, \(X) {
  nulls <- lm(X$Y ~ 1, X)
  full_models <- lm(X$Y ~ ., X)
  forward <- stats::step(object = nulls, direction = 'forward',
                         scope = formula(full_models), trace = FALSE) }) )
```

Where datasets is a list of N data.table objects (which are also data.frames as well of course). It was created using the following code which is carried over into the new script:

```
folderpath <- "C:/Users/Spencer/.../datasets folder"
paths_list <- list.files(path = folderpath, full.names = T, recursive = T)

datasets <- lapply(paths_list, fread)

datasets <- lapply(datasets, function(i) {i[-1:-3, ]})
datasets <- lapply(datasets, \(X) { lapply(X, as.numeric) })
datasets <- lapply(datasets, function(i) { as.data.table(i) })
```

And yet, more or less copying+pasting it but changing the actual function from step to the olsrr version for it, it does not run:

```
> set.seed(11)      # for reproducibility
> BE_fits <- lapply(X = datasets, \(i) {
+     full_models <- lm(i$Y ~ ., data = i)
+     backward <- ols_step_backward_aic(full_models) })
Error in eval(model$call$data) : object 'i' not found
Called from: eval(model$call$data)
Browse[1]> Q
```

Then, because, later in my working script, I had gotten around similar problems using seq_along, so I tried that here as well and ended up with the problem in the title of this question:

```
> BE_fits <- lapply(seq_along(datasets), \(i) {
+   full_models <- lm(i$Y ~ ., data = i)
+   backward <- ols_step_backward_aic(full_models) })
Error in model.frame.default(formula = i$Y ~ ., data = i, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : 
  'data' must be a data.frame, environment, or list
Called from: model.frame.default(formula = i$Y ~ ., data = i, drop.unused.levels = TRUE)
Browse[1]> Q
```

However, because of this line earlier:
datasets <- lapply(datasets, function(i) { as.data.table(i) })

Each of the N data sets in datasets, which is itself a list, is a data.table and a data.frame, as you can see below:

```
> class(datasets)
[1] "list"
> class(datasets[[5]])
[1] "data.table" "data.frame"
```

In order to demonstrate proof of concept to myself on a single dataset, I ran the following which does work:
full <- lm(datasets[[5]]$Y ~ ., data = datasets[[5]])
backward_elimination <- ols_step_backward_aic(full)

p.s. Other alterations I have already tried.

**1st.** Using the suggested answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71654992/boxcox-error-in-model-frame-default-data-must-be-a-data-frame-environment), I also tried it out after painstakingly typing X1+X2+X3...+X30, but it still gave the same error, as you can see below:

```
> BE_fits <- lapply(X = seq_along(datasets), \(ds) {
+   full_models <- lm(ds$Y ~ X1+X2+X3+X4+X5+X6+X7+X8+X9+X10+X11+X12+X13+X14+X15+X16+X17+X18+X19+X20+X21+X22+X23+X24+X25+X26+X27+X28+X29+X30, 
+                     data = ds)
+   backward <- ols_step_backward_aic(full_models) })
Error in model.frame.default(formula = ds$Y ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 + X5 +  : 
  'data' must be a data.frame, environment, or list
Called from: model.frame.default(formula = ds$Y ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 + X5 + 
    X6 + X7 + X8 + X9 + X10 + X11 + X12 + X13 + X14 + X15 + X16 + 
    X17 + X18 + X19 + X20 + X21 + X22 + X23 + X24 + X25 + X26 + 
    X27 + X28 + X29 + X30, data = ds, drop.unused.levels = TRUE)
Browse[1]> Q
```

**2nd.** Just to do a quick sanity check to make absolutely sure it wasn't because I was using data.tables instead of data.frames, I ran:

```
datasets <- lapply(datasets, function(i) { as.data.frame(i) })
```

Then re-ran my backward stepwise regression, but it gave the same error yet again.

**3rd.** I also tried to reiterate that each the data set being used for each regression is a regression within my lm function via in this way:

```
> BE_fits <- lapply(seq_along(datasets), \(ds) {
+   full_models <- lm(ds$Y ~ ., as.data.frame(ds))
+   backward <- ols_step_backward_aic(full_models) })
Error in ds$Y : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
Called from: eval(predvars, data, env)
Browse[1]> Q
```

But this error may have been the weirdest, because if this error were valid, then the code I used many times to run the Backward Elimination Stepwise Regressions using my original "BE and FS Stepwise Regressions" script would never have worked!

**4th.** The one other idea I tried was inspired by the way I ran the single BE Stepwise Regression on the single 5th dataset, so I used the same double bracket subset syntax, but now it can no longer find the "i" when I run it:

```
> BE_fits <- lapply(seq_along(datasets), \(i) {
+   full_models <- lm(datasets[[i]]$Y ~ ., data = datasets[[i]])
+   backward <- ols_step_backward_aic(full_models) })
Error in eval(model$call$data) : object 'i' not found
Called from: eval(model$call$data)
Browse[1]> Q
```